# JavaScript stored procedure API equivalent for Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using JavaScript stored procedure API in Snowflake to get the structure of the procedures, using the following code:

```
   GSF1 = 'var sql_command ="<SQLCOMMAND>";
           var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command} ); 
           var res = stmt.execute();'
```

What is the equivalent code of the above, which can be used in Redshift?

My requirement is to convert Snowflake stored procedures into Redshift stored procedures.

Comment: Given Redshift is based of PostgreSQL, perhaps you want to learn PostgreSQL Stored Procedures. Of which are functionally the same as stored functions in PostgreSQL (except SP allow some cool transactions flow control.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html